# "List all non-isomorphic trees with exactly 6 vertices"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I've been given a question which asks me to "list all non-isomorphic trees with exactly 6 vertices".

Whilst trying to work out how to tell whether a graph is isomorphic (which I still don't understand how to do) I stumbled across the answer to this question, shown in the image below:

[image]

However, I'm not sure why this is the answer. In my notes, it says that every graph is isomorphic to its compliment **[*]** (though I also do not understand why this is). Looking at, for example, the second graph from the left. This graph has a connected compliment. Doesn't this mean that it should be isomorphic, since the mapping from itself to its compliment is an isomorphism?

Also from my notes, I've seen that if $G=(V,E)$ and $G'=(V',E')$ and $|E| \neq |E'|$, then $G$ and $G'$ are not isomorphic. Surely this contradicts **[*]**, since many graphs have a compliment with a different number of edges?

Thanks

Comment: It is not true that every graph is isomorphic to its complement - for example, the complement of each tree in the above list has a cycle, unlike the tree itself. Perhaps the text meant to say that taking the complement *preserves* isomorphism (i.e. if $G,H$ are isomorphic, then so are their complements)?

Comment: Okay, that makes things slightly clearer. I'm still not sure how you can tell that the 6 graphs in the example are non-isomorphic. Any advice here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only the first graph has a vertex of degree 5; only the sixth graph has two vertices of degree 1 and four vertices of degree 2; etc.

Comment: Note that this criterion (equal number of nodes of degrees 1/2/...) is a necessary, but not sufficient condition for isomorphism: in particular, the numbers are the same for the third and fifth tree.

Comment: A good way would be to list all trees of diameter 2, 3 , 4, 5.